# Warn me about 'uncategorized' posts

Tags: categories

I always want new posts to have a category, but sometimes I forget.

How can I make Wordpress warn me when I'm about something 'uncategorized'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Category Reminder plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-reminder/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Change the category name uncategorized to some other. I usually make this "Other". In case you want notification in front end you can add a alert or some Red graphics with post loop by code`<?php if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) { do_something(); } ?>` so only you can see it. check http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/03/27/how-to-check-if-a-wordpress-user-is-an-administrator/

Its a easy one :) but if you want to show something like a javascript popup in admin when you click the update/publish button. You have to add a javascript in admin area like this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_script_from_your_theme.2C_excluding_admin_area 
then you can check if uncategorized is checked when user clicked on publish button.

You have to check the id of the checkbox of the category and update button. I think the javascript will not very hard.

Thanks let me know if it was helpful or not.

Comment: I think Milo's answer was a little easier to follow, sorry.

Comment: no problem at all! :)